# Public space in front of a theatre

Tags: theater, architecture

I would like to ask, if there is any word describing public space in front of a theater. Something like vallation, but specific for theaters.

I need to do architectural research, but can't find any corresponding word.

Thank you.

Comment: I would use ***theater plaza***: https://books.google.com/books?id=pLRgcXZgN-YC&pg=PA295&dq=%22theater+plaza%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22theater%20plaza%22&f=false

Comment: Footpath or Sidewalk or Roadside would cover it, if the theater was beside a roadway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sydney Opera House refers to the area in front of the theatre as ["The Forecourt"](http://www.sydneyoperahouse.com/the_building/venues/forecourt.aspx?mencid=meganav:The_Building:Venue_Info:Forecourt), which is a generic term for the area in front of any large building.